# Transforming SQL Query to Django Expression

Tags: python, sql, django

Assuming I have the following Django models and the according SQL-Tables with some data. I have simplified the models so that it is clearer.

UserAnswer:

```py
class UserAnswer(models.Model):
  partquestion = models.ForeignKey(PartQuestion)
  answer = models.CharField()
```

| id | answer | partquestion_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 667 | 1 |

PartQuestion:

```py
class PartQuestion(models.Model):
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
  part = models.ForeignKey(Part)
```

| id | question_id | part_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

Solution:

```py
class SingleInputSolution(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    content = models.CharField()
```

| id | content | question_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 667 | 1 |
| 2 | 85 | 2 |

I want to get all User answers where the answer is equal to the solution of the according question. I've came up with this SQL-Query but can't really think of how to implement this into a Djano query:

```sql
select * from (useranswer join partquestion on 
useranswer.partquestion_id = partquestion.id) join solution on 
partquestion.question_id = solution.question_id where answer=content;
```

This will output the following:

| useranswer.id | useranswer.answer | useranswer.partquestion_id | partquestion.id | partquestion.question_id | partquestion.part_id | solution.id | solution.content | solution.question_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 667 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 667 | 1 |

I just can't get my head around this concept in Django. Maybe using F-Expressions and some stuff.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can you please share your model. It would make it much easier to help you. For example, it's unclear how the models are related to each other (via foreign key?).

Comment: @yagus Oh sure, sorry. I added the model definitions to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay well I just figured it out myself after reading the answer and comments from @Swift.

It's:

```py
UserAnswer.objects.filter(partquestion__question__solution__content=F('answer'))
```

It's pretty simple now after I got it but I just tried using `solution_set` instead of just `solution`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use values and the `__` relations to traverse the foreign keys.

```
UserAnswer.objects.values('id', 'answer', 'partquestion_id', 'partquestion_set__id', 'partquestion_set__question_id')
```

Unfortunately it isn't obvious enough to me how to get those columns for the last table, but I hope that from this answer you can see how to do it?

Comment: But how will the 'partquestion_set__id' work? It is a queryset with (sometimes) multiple objects in it. Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: Its the reverse relationships between them in this case. When you create a foreign key, django creates this partquestion_set attribute which is many to one relationship.

Comment: Take the classic Book and Author example, an Author can have many books. They relate via an FK from Book to Author. Django creates author.book_set automatically and you can get all books by an author. You can traverse any number of relationships.

Comment: Yeah I thought of this too, but didn't get it to work. I finally got the solution. I needed to access it just by using UserAnswer.objects.filter('solution',...) and not the 'solition_set' as I'm using when accessing the actual objects set. Thanks for your answer and comments which got me to the right direction. I will post the answer how I did it.